# Prove that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}$ has at least n+1 zeros on $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, roots

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$\ $(-1,1)$. Prove that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}$ has at least n+1 zeros on $(-1,1)$

My attempt :

- Assume $f$ is strictly positive  (if not n=0 works). Let $Z(f^{(n)})$ the number of zeros of $f^{(n)}$ on $(-1,1)$. Then we have:
  $$
  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\;f^{(n)}(-1)=f^{(n)}(1)=0
  $$
  so that iterating the Rolle theorem to the successive derivatives of f we have 
  $$
   \;Z(f^{(k+1)}) \geq Z(f^{(k)}) +1
  $$
  thus, by induction :
  $$
  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \;Z(f^{(n+1)}) \geq Z(f^{(n)}) +1
  $$
  Therefore,
  $$
  Z(f^{(n)}) \geq n
  $$
  **How can I find an another zero ?**

**I'm still looking for an another proof which does not use the lemma** ..,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I imagine you need to find these zeros in $(-1,1)$. Correct?

Comment: I tried to use $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{} \exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)&\text{if }|x|\lt1\\ 0&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$ to find a counterexample, but the third derivative has $5$ zeros in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud   I'm sure that the result is true.

Comment: This question [was re-asked (by yourself)](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157475/) on MathOverflow.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks to mention that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe Julien's proof is right and is also elegant, although there are a lot of typos in his write up. I'll rewrite it here (as Community Wiki), since there seems to be some doubt about that. Of course, this doesn't answer Julien's request for a different proof, but I see nothing wrong with his proof

I introduce the notation $Z(h)$ for the number of zeroes of $h$ on $(-1,1)$.

Let $f$ be as stated. If $f$ vanishes on $(-1,1)$ we are done so, without loss of generality, let $f(x)$ be positive on $(-1,1)$.

For any positive integer $k$, define
$$
g:=x\to \frac{f(x)}{(1-x^2)^k} \mbox{ for } |x|<1, \mbox{ and } 0 \mbox{ otherwise}
$$ 
L'Hospital's rule shows that $g$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, and $g$ is identically zero outside $(-1,1)$.

Choose $k$ such that 
$$
0 = f(-1) \ < \ f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) (1-\frac14)^{-k} \ >\  f(0)\  < \ f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (1-\frac14)^{-k}  \ > \ f(1) = 0.
$$
So
$$
0 = g(-1) \ < \ g(-1/2) \ >\  g(0)\ <\  g(1/2)\ >\ g(1) = 0.$$

Then $g'$ must be positive somewhere on $(-1,-1/2)$, negative somewhere on $(-1/2,0)$, positive somewhere on $(0,1/2)$ and negative somewhere on $(1/2,1)$. Thus $Z(g^{(1)}) \geq 3$, and the result holds for $g$ (instead of $f$), with $n=1$.

We will show that $Z(f^{(2k+1)}) \geq 2k+3$.

**Lemma** Let $p(x)$ be identically $0$ outside $(-1,1)$ and let $a$ be a real number not in $(-1,1)$. Set $q(x) = p(x) (x-a)$. Then $Z(q^{(n+1)}(x)) \geq Z(p^{(n)}(x))+1$.

**Proof** Let the zeroes of $p^{(n)}$ be $-1 < r_1 < r_2 < \cdots < r_m < 1$ and set $r_0=-1$ and $r_{m+1}=1$. Then $(x-a)^{n+1} p^{(n)}(x)$ vanishes at all the $r_i$, so by Rolle's theorem, $Z(\frac{d}{dx} ( (x-a)^{n+1} p^{(n)}(x) )) \geq m+1$. But $\frac{d}{dx} ( (x-a)^{n+1} p^{(n)}(x) ) = (x-a)^n q^{(n+1)}$, and $(x-a)^{n}$ doesn't vanish on $[-1,1]$, so $Z(q^{(n+1)}) \geq m+1$ as desired. $\square$

Basically, the lemma says that throwing in a non vanishing linear factor doesn't make the Rolle's theorem bound worse.

Now set $h_0 = g$, $h_1 = (1-x) h_0$, $h_2 =  (1+x) h_1$, $h_3 = (1-x) h_2$, $h_4 = (1+x) h_3$ etcetera, until $h_{2k} = (1-x^2)^k h_0 = f$. Applying the lemma repeatedly gives
$$Z(f^{(2k+1)}) \geq Z(h_{2k-1}^{(2k)} )+1 \geq Z(h_{2k-2}^{2k-1})+2 \geq \cdots \geq Z(h_0^{(1)}) + 2k \geq 3+2k$$
as desired.

Comment: $f(1)$ in the equation after after "choose $k$ large enough" should be $0$, no?

Comment: I don't think $a\notin(-1,1)$ is needed.  
If $a \in (-1, 1)$ and $a \neq r_i$ then Rolle's theorem yields $m+2$ zeros so $Z(q^{(n+1)}) \geq m+1$ must hold since $(x-a)^n$ has only 1 zero.  
If $a = r_i$ then Rolle's theorem yields $m+1$ zeros so $Z(q^{(n+1)}) \geq m+1$ because $(x-a)^n$ vanish only at $x=a$ which is a root of $q^{(n+1)}(x) = (n+1)p^{(n)}(x) + (x-a)p^{(n+1)}(x)$.

Answer (score 11):

- Lemma: Let f a such function and $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ a polynomial and $deg(P)=d$ without zeros on $(-1,1)$. Then: 
  $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, Z((fP)^{(n+d)}) \geq Z(f^{(n)})+d
  $$

*Proof*. By induction it's sufficient to prove $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$\ $(-1,1)$ : 
$$Z((g)^{(n+1)}) \geq Z(f^{(n)})+1
$$
where $g(x)=(x-\alpha)f(x)$
,

Moreover, $g^{(n+1)}(x)=(x-\alpha)^{-(1-n)}\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl((x-\alpha)^{n}f^{(n)}(x)\Bigr)$. Then $g^{(n+1)}$ vanishes at least once again on (-1,1). **QED**

- Let p an integer such that
  $$
  \Bigl(\frac{3}{4}\Bigr)^p < \min\left(\frac{f(\frac12)}{f(0)},\frac{f(-\frac12)}{f(0)}\right)
  $$
  and 
  $$
  g(x)=(1-x^2)^{-p}f(x),\qquad g(-1)=g(1)=0
  $$
  Then 
  $$
  g(-1)<g(-1/2),\qquad g(-1/2)>g(0),\qquad g(0)<g(1/2),\qquad g(1/2)>g(1).
  $$
  Thus, $g'$ vanishes at least three times on (-1,1), **by the lemma** we get 
  $$
  Z(f^{(n+2p)}) \geq Z(g^{(n)})+2p
  $$
  and we have (with $n=1$) 
  $$
  Z(f^{(1+2p)}) \geq 3+2p
  $$
  **Therefore**,   $f^{(m)}$ for $m\geq 2p+1$ has at least $m+2$ zeros on $(-1,1)$

Comment: I do not understand the proof of the lemma. We have $g^{(n)}(x)=(x-\alpha)f^{(n)}(x)+nf^{(n-1)}(x)$, and I am not sure what to conclude about zeros of $g$ from this. Also, I think in the statement of the lemma you may want to say something about the zeros of $P$ being real.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo You have right, I made ​​a mistake, I edited.

Comment: Isn't it $f(0)$ on the denominator? Because, you want $g(0)<min(g(1/2),g(-1/2))$.

Comment: @i707107 No, I don't think so. Because I have chosen $g(x)=(1-x^2)^{-p}f(x)$

Comment: You are using $g(0)<g(1/2)$, that is equivalent to $f(0)<(3/4)^{-p} f(1/2)$. Thus, $(3/4)^p < f(1/2) / f(0)$.

Comment: @i707107  You have right, my apologies.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I understand the lemma, assuming "such a function" means "smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ and vanishing outside $(-1,1)$". Let $f^{(n)}$ have $k$ zeroes $z_1$, $z_2$, ..., $z_k$ on $(-1,1)$ and set $z_0=-1$, $z_{k+1}=1$. Then $(x-\alpha)^n f^{(n)}(x)$ is zero at $z_i$ and $z_{i+1}$, so $\frac{d}{dx} (x-\alpha)^n f^{(n)}(x)$ has a zero in $(z_i, z_{i+1})$, so $g^{(n+1)}(x) = (z-\alpha)^{-n+1} \frac{d}{dx} (x-\alpha)^n f^{(n)}(x)$ has a zero in $(z_i, z_{i+1})$. I'm still trying to digest how the lemma is used: Have the variables $f$ and $g$ switched places?

Comment: I do get that instead of saying $P$ has no zeroes on $(-1,1)$, the proof should have the stronger statement that all zeroes of $P$ are real, and not in $(-1,1)$. But that is the case in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\cH{\mathcal{H}}\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$A bit more than the question asks for is true. Let $\cH$ be the class of function $f: \RR \to \RR$ for which $f^{(n)}(-1) = f^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for all $n$. Note that, for  $f \in \cH$, the sequence $Z(f^{(n)})$ is weakly increasing. I will show that $Z(f^{(n)})-n \to \infty$. Let's define $L(f) = \lim_{n \to \infty} Z(f^{(n)})-n$.

We recall the lemma from my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/676724/448):

**Lemma** Let $a \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$ and $p \in \cH$. Put $q(x) = (x-a) p(x)$. Then $Z(q^{(n+1)}) \geq Z(p^{(n)})+1$.

We can rewrite this as $Z(q^{n+1}) - (n+1) \geq Z(p^{(n)}) - n$ and take the limit to deduce.

**Corollary 1** With notation as in the lemma, $L(q) \geq L(p)$.

Using this repeatedly

**Corollary 2** For any positive integers $A$ and $B$, we have $L(f) \geq L(f (1+z)^{-A} (1-z)^{-B})$.

Now, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $L(f)<\infty$. Replacing $f$ by one of its derivatives, we may assume that $Z(f^{(n)})  = n +c$ for all $n$. Let the zeroes of $f$ be $-1< r_1 < r_2 < \cdots < r_c< 1$ and without loss of generality suppose $f$ is positive on $(-1,r_1)$. But then if we choose $A$ and $B$ very large with $(A-B)/(A+B) \in (-1,r_1)$, then $g(z) : = f (1+z)^{-A} (1-z)^{-B})$ will have positive second derivative at $(A-B)/(A+B)$, so $g'$ has at least $3$ zeroes in $(-1, r_1)$, as well as at least one zero in each of $(r_1,r_2)$, $(r_2, r_3)$, ..., $(r_{c-1},r_c)$, $(r_c, 1)$, so $Z(g') \geq c+3$ and $L(g) \geq c+2$.

This contradicts corollary $2$.

---

In [a different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379252), the OP asks about functions with $f^{(n)}(-1) = f^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for $n \geq 1$, $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Clearly, if $f$ is such a function then $f' \in \cH$, so the bound also applies to such functions. In the comments to that question, there were a bunch of off by $1$ errors, so I thought I'd write up an answer to show that $L(f)$ is infinite anyway, and the off by $1$'s don't matter.

Comment: I must be missing something. I suppose $g(z)=f(z)(1+z)^{-A}(1-z)^{-B}$. I can confirm that for $y=\frac{A-B}{A+B}$, $g'(y)$ has the same sign as $f'(y)$ and that $g''(y)$ can can be made to be positive. That said, I don't follow the rest of the argument.