# Does the n'th derivative of a smooth transition have to have more than n+1 roots for some n?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I'm wondering if the space
$$S=\left\{f\in C^{\infty}([0,1])\ \ :\ \ f(0)=0\bigwedge f(1)=1\bigwedge\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(1)=0\right\}$$
contains an element $f_0$ such that $f_0^{(n)}$ has at most $n+1$ roots for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Intuitively I'm somewhat inclined to think it's false. Do anyone know if this holds, or how I should go on about finding out?

If $f_0^{(n)}$ has $n+1$ roots, then by the mean value theorem $f_0^{(n+1)}$ has $n$ distinct roots in the interior of the support in addition to the boundary points being roots. Hence by induction $f_0^{(n)}$ must have $n+1$ roots for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

As to whether the lower bound is non-strict, I think maybe the way to go is to assume that $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $a_i \in S$ and $a_i^{(i)}$ having at most $i+1$ roots. Because if those properties imply that not all derivatives of $a_i$ remain bounded as $i\to\infty$, then no such sequence can have an element of $S$ as limit, and so the lower bound must be strict.

I made some numerically experiments with linear programs which indicated the existence of such a sequence where also $\sup_x a_i^{(1)}(x)<2$. So several derivatives must be considered simultaneously.

Comment: Have you tried with trigonometric functions?

Comment: Trig won't do it, but what about something like $e^{-1/(x^2(x-1)^2)}\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Do those roots include $0$ and $1$? EDIT: Oh, misread

Comment: Oh, I made $f(1)=0$ as well. Oops. Surely that's fixable. :)

Comment: You want large numbers of roots for all the derivatives, too, @yanko.

Comment: well the derivatives are $0$ in an interval near 0 and near 1.

Comment: @yanko I mean exactly, because I know how to prove that n+1 is necessary

Comment: Oh, I see. That will sure do it. @lasenH: Then you need to edit and say *precisely* $n+1$ roots? ... Hmm

Comment: @yanko $1$ _is_ a root of $f^{(n)}$

Comment: I think the integral of [this thing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vashrzq3sf) would work

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Thank you very much. Can't believe I never came across that site..

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Here we have the condition $f(1) = 1$, not $f(1) = 0$. If we apply the result from there to $f'$, which fits the assumptions of that question, we get a $k$ such that $f^{(2k+2)} = (f')^{(2k+1)}$ has at least $2k+3$ zeros in $(-1,1)$, but that's not quite enough for this question. If the result for $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ can be strengthened to give an $n$ with $Z(f^{(n)}) > n+2$, that would directly give the answer here, but I don't immediately see how to do that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, apologies for missing that. So it isn't an actual duplicate, but I believe I can adopt the answer to that question to handle this one.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer That would be awesome.

Comment: @DanielFischer Its one more roots than enough for this question. The answer to the other question yields $2k+5$ roots in the $[-1,1]$ for $f^{2k+2}\circ (x\mapsto 2 x-1)$ where $f\in S$ is that of this question. I asked for more than $2k+3$

Comment: @lasenH How? I don't see it. If we take $f$ from this question, then $g = f'$ satisfies the premises of the other question. The result there gives $2k+3$ zeros of $g^{(2k+1)} = f^{(2k+2)}$, so only $n+1$ zeros of $f^{(n)}$ with $n = 2k+2$. Do you apply the result to something else than $f'$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Those $2k+3$ zeros are in the interior. All derivatives have two zeros at the boundary, which I included as roots in this question

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I forgot about the zeros at the boundary, which are counted here, so the result at the other question fully solves this as is.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Can you link your answer in an answer here so I can award the bounty

Comment: @lasenH I've removed the bounty to close this as a duplicate. You can however start another bounty on that question. You'll have to wait 24 hours before you can award that then, but I don't think that's a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that the answer to your question is *yes* and my candidate for a function would be as follows. Let us work on the interval $[-1,1]$ and consider the [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)
$$ \psi(x) = \exp\left(\frac {-1}{1-x^2} \right)\,.$$
Then all derivatives at the endpoints vanish,
$$ \psi^{(n)}(-1) = \psi^{(n)}(1) = 0\,.$$
Now define
$$ f(x) = a \int_{-1}^x \psi(y) \,dy\,,$$
and choose $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(1) = 1$.

To prove your required properties one would need explicit expressions for the derivatives of $\psi$ which involve polynomials of high degrees. I believe that intuitively $\psi$ and its derivatives have no more roots than necessary, but I have not checked the details.

Comment: $f^{(n)}(x)$ has $n+3$ roots for $n=4$

Comment: You are right. I overlooked this.