# How to prove this lemma related to Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, roots

For any function $f$ denote by $Z(f)$ and $Z_o(f)$ the cardinalities of $f^{-1}(0)\cap[0,1]$ and $f^{-1}(0)\cap(0,1)$, respectively. Let $H=\{f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}): \text{supp}(f) = [0,1]\}$

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664741) we have
**Lemma 1**
Let $q:x\mapsto(x-r)p(x)$ where $p\in H$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $Z(q^{(n)})\geq Z(p^{(n-1)})+1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof**
Note that $q^{(n)}(x) = n p^{(n-1)}(x) + (x-r)p^{(n)}(x)$. Hence $r$ is a root of $q^{(n)}$ if and only if it is a root of $p^{(n-1)}$. Moreover we have

$$\underbrace{(x-r)^{n-1}q^{(n)}(x)}_{\text{LHS}} = n (x-r)^{n-1} p^{(n-1)}(x) + (x-r)^np^{(n)}(x) = \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}(x-r)^n p^{(n-1)}(x)}_{\text{RHS}}$$

If $q^{(n)}(r) = 0$ then $Z(q^{(n)}) - 2 = Z_o(\text{LHS}) = Z_o(\text{RHS}) \geq Z(p^{(n-1)}) - 1$.
If $q^{(n)}(r) \neq 0$ then $Z(q^{(n)}) - 1 = Z_o(\text{LHS}) = Z_o(\text{RHS}) \geq Z(p^{(n-1)})\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{q.e.d.}$
$\text{ }$

The following modification
**Lemma 2**
Let $q:x\mapsto(x-r)(x-\bar{r})p(x)$ where $p\in H$ and $r\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Then $Z(q^{(n)})\geq Z(p^{(n-2)})+2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$.

I tried to prove the same way by writing

$$\frac{j(x)k(x)}{(x-r)(x-\bar{r})}q^{(n)}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(j(x)^2 k(x)\frac{d}{dx}j(x)^{-1}p^{(n-2)}(x)\right)$$
where $\frac{d}{dx}$ is differentiation along the real axis and
$j(x)=c_1(x-r)^{1-n}+c_2(x-\bar{r})^{1-n}$
$k(x) = c_3 ((x-r)(x-\bar{r}))^n$
$c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb{C}$

The real and imaginary part of $j(x)^{-1}$ are proportional, and $j(x)k(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ when choosing
$c_1 = e^{i d_1}\\c_2=e^{i d_2}\\c_3=e^{-i\cdot 
 (d_1+d_2)/2}\\d_1,d_2\in\mathbb{R}$

but even then I couldn't get Rolle's theorem to work unless $j(x)$ has no roots on $(0,1)$. I have looked at many functions/different $n$s and even when choosing $r$ such that $j(x)$ has such roots, it seems impossible to find a counterexample to the lemma.

How to prove the lemma?

Or maybe this simpler version which remains when removing some of the assumptions:
If $p$ is smooth with $p^{(n-2)}$ having $m$ roots on $[0,1]$, then how to prove that the $n$'th derivative of $x \mapsto p(x)(x-r)(x-\bar{r})$ has at least $m-2$ roots on $(0,1)$.

Comment: In the linked question, $r$ is assumed not in $(0,1)$. Do you want some analogous hypothesis in Lemma 2?

Comment: What does the subscript $c$ signify in your notation $C^{\infty}_c$?

Comment: @WillFisher I mean the space of [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), but the other conditions implies the $c$ so it is redundant

Comment: I take it "for any function $f$" means "for any real-valued function $f$ of a real variable"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Any function whose domain contains $[0,1]$ and whose codomain contains $\{0\}$

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I'm interested in how to prove lemma 2 further than for those choices of $r$, $n$ and $p$ that implies that $j$ has no roots on $(0,1)$

Comment: In the last (simpler) lemma still $r$ purely imaginary?

Comment: @mucciolo The real part can be non-zero